# I just can't slice Ember Data store output

Tags: ember.js

I'm JS beginner and recently using ember.js for ui development I came across a problem that I can't solve.
I'm trying to reduce amount of posts to fit them on one page. Simply calling slice method on return value of this.get('store').find() doesn't work. I also tried to trim content of return value of all function, but still without success. Any ideas?

Comment: Please add your code to your answer, otherwise it will be hard to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
App.YourController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    arrangedContent: function() {        
        return this.get('content').slice(0 , 10);
    }.property('content')
});
```

Where `YourController` is the controller that belongs to your route. So the content will be the resolved promise from `this.store.find('modelName')`. The `arrangedContent` property is the place where you modify the content when you want to perform filtering, ordering etc. Without changing the content directly and preserving all the data.

Give a look in that sample http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/pwQ5b/

Comment: It looks that it worked, but I don't understand why your solution work unless I use {{#each item in model}} ? And why I have to use ArrayController?

Comment: If you use {{#each item in model}}, it will iterate directlly in the model, and the model doesn't have the arrangedContent, just the controller. So you need to use {{#each item in controller}}, {{#each item in this}} or {{#each item in arrangedContent}}. In the fidde I use {{#each}} and it's the same like {{#each this}}.

Answer (score 0):

If you really are calling slice on the return value of this.get('store').find you will run into trouble. The find function returns a promise and you need the result the promise resolves to.

You can solve this in one of two ways:

If you are using the standard Ember pattern for loading in your model, you should have a model function defined in your route. This will actually wait until the result is resolved and in your controller you can call slice on this.get('content')

If you are loading your data within the controller you will need to so something like below:

```
c = this
this.store.find('myModel').then(function(result) {
    c.set('paginatedContent', result.slice(0, 10));
});
```

Here we are waiting for the promise returned by find to resolve to a result before setting the paginated content based on that result.

Comment: I use standard ember pattern for loading, but I was trying to keep the data processing inside model. Probably that was my fault...

Comment: Pagination is definitely a function of the controller. On a side note, if you have control over the api, you are far better off putting pagination in on the api side and then processing meta data on the client (Ember) side.